# How to get the visible text in ie with vba?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some text from a webpage using excel. The page has a lot of js with decision trees, so when I use ie.document.body.innertext, I will see those if statements. I do not want to deal with those. I want the result that they output onto the screen. outertext doesn't work either because it appears to give the same result as innertext. Innerhtml & outerhtml also show the decision trees.

Any ideas on how to get the visible text that's painted on the screen?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=69569  I don't usually recommend `SendKeys` but it might work for this. There are other methods if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of sendkeys because I've done a pretty good job avoiding it. I can give it a try, but what kinds of other options are there?

Comment: Very very basic, try Data > Import from Web then enter the desired URL.  This won't allow you to do any IE automation, however.

Comment: Otherwise, I would recommend using the Selenium Wrapper which adds a LOT of functionality to automating web browsers, and you can use it with IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the Selenium Webdriver, which extends the ability to do browser-based automation.

[HERE](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-firefox-or-chrome-with-vba-and-selenium/) is a good overview.

[HERE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) is the download/documentation.

Here is an example of its use:

```
Sub GetWebPageText(url$)
' REQUIRES REFERENCE TO THE SELENIUM WEBDRIVER TYPE LIBRARY
Dim selenium As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver

selenium.Start "InternetExplorer", url

selenium.Open url

Debug.Print selenium.getBodyText



End Sub
```