# Pressing the Get Route button from AA Route Planner VBA

Tags: vba, excel, automation, explorer

I am trying to automate Route Planner Searches in Internet Explorer. i have the following code that is close to what i need but instead of pressing the "Get Route" button it picks up the "Find A Car" button instead. once i get that sorted i want to be able to get the result of the distance in miles and input back to Excel. thanks.

i think i have managed to find the code for the element i need to select but not sure as to how i go about it any advice/help?

`<a href="#" class="getRouteBtn" onclick="onGetRouteClicked(false);return false;" style="background-position: 0px -32px;"><span style="background-position: 100% -32px;">Get route</span></a>`

```
Public Sub route()

Dim startpc As Object
Dim endpc As Object
Dim objie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'microsoft internet controls   (shdocvw.dll)
Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'Microsoft HTML Object Library
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Set objie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

With objie
.navigate "http://www.theaa.com/route-planner/index.jsp" ' Main page
.Visible = 1
Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

Set startpc = objie.document.getElementById("routeFrom")
Set endpc = objie.document.getElementById("routeTo")
startpc.Value = ActiveCell.Value
endpc.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
'click Button
Set htmlDoc = .document
Set htmlColl = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
Do While htmlDoc.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
If Trim(htmlInput.Type) = "submit" Then
htmlInput.Click
Exit For
End If
Next htmlInput
End With
End Sub
```

[PateBin Link](http://pastebin.com/x4L2FbNt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this loop here, you're asking the program to find the first `"submit"` element with an `"input" tag, and click it.

```
For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
    If Trim(htmlInput.Type) = "submit" Then
        htmlInput.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

That's not right, because the "Get Route" button doesn't have an `"input"` tag, 
Looking at this element in Dev tools in Chrome, it doesn't have a reliable `id` property but you could find it using `GetElementsByClassName("getRouteBtn")` or you can use its parent `div` element which does have an `ID`, like:

```
'## Here, the .Children(0) will handle the actual button, which is the
'   Div element's first child element
htmlDoc.GetElementByID("getRouteWrapper").Children(0)
```

[image]

After you click that element, wait for the page to load and the resulting distance element *does* have an `id` property, so you can use `GetElementByID("routeDistanceValue")`

[image]

This seems to be working, though note that I used `InternetExplorer.Application` class for the `objie` instead of the `ShDocVw.InternetExplorer`.

```
Public Sub route()

Dim startpc As Object
Dim endpc As Object
Dim objie As Object 
Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'Microsoft HTML Object Library
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Set objie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With objie
    .navigate "http://www.theaa.com/route-planner/index.jsp" ' Main page
    .Visible = True
    Call ReadyLoop(objie)
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    Set startpc = objie.document.GetElementByID("routeFrom")
    Set endpc = objie.document.GetElementByID("routeTo")
    startpc.Value = ActiveCell.Value
    endpc.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    'click Button
    Set htmlDoc = .document
    'Find the "getRouteBtn"
    Dim btn As Object
    Set btn = htmlDoc.GetElementByID("getRouteWrapper").Children(0)

    If Not btn Is Nothing Then btn.Click
    Call ReadyLoop(htmlDoc)

    'Get the distance item:
    Dim htmlDist As Object
    Set htmlDist = htmlDoc.GetElementByID("routeDistanceValue")
    If Not htmlDist Is Nothing Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = htmlDist.InnerText
    Else
        MsgBox "Element 'routDistanceValue' not found!", vbCritical
        GoTo EarlyExit
    End If
End With

Exit Sub
EarlyExit:
End Sub

Sub ReadyLoop(obj As Object)
Do While Not obj.ReadyState = 4 And Not obj.ReadyState = "complete"
    DoEvents
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. it is almost there. your code works except that i get the message box "routDistanceValue not found" even though the results are there on the page. having a look at the script i cant find the ID routedistancevalue anywhere. also i cant find the actual distance in the script either but when i look in chrome i can see this?

Comment: @mal try `Dim objie As Object` and then `Set objie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`. That is actually the method that I used instead of the `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer` class.

Comment: Thanks David. i have amended my code following your suggestion but unfortunately get the same result-message box error message. i am using internet explorer 8, could this be the reason i am getting different results to you?

Comment: Possibly. I don't have IE8 but I know there are problems with such older versions not rendering correctly.  You might have to use another method...

Comment: Can you do the View Source option to see page's HTML, and dump it on PasteBin so I can see what HTML is actually there?

Comment: Also, if you're able to download additional library references, I would [strongly recommend using the Selenium Web Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281782/how-to-get-the-visible-text-in-ie-with-vba/28282187#28282187); you can fully automate Chrome through that library, so that should resolve the IE8 problems, and it's a bit more intuitive to use as well.

Comment: I have pasted the entire HTML code onto PasteBin for you to view. its called AA Route Planner. Thanks again for your help with this. unfortunately Internet Explorer 8 is what we have available, failing that my only other option would be Mozilla Firefox. thanks again.

Comment: You can use Firefox with Selenium, too. I'd definitely try to go that route. Can you add the Pastebin link in your Question (above)?

Comment: link added at bottom of original question.

Comment: OK so that's really weird because I don't see it in View Source via Chrome, either, but it's clearly there via Chrome Dev Tools.  You could try `Set htmlDist = htmlDoc.GetElementsByClassName("mapSidePanel")(1)(1)(2)(1).InnerText` but if the resulting HTML (which is apparently served by a Javascript function) differs in IE8, your results may vary, and that may also be why the particular named element is returning `Nothing`, because it might not exist in IE8 output.

Comment: thanks for trying David, but now i get object doesn't support this method etc error

Comment: Yep that suggests the object doesn't exist. Note that guess relies on same object structure which probably isn't a safe assumption... use Selenium, you'd have it solved by now if you use that instead of IE :)